# Asterisk sip trunk peer NIC

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, 3cx

I'm working with Asterisk 14.7.6 and Freepbx 14.0.13.23 in a ec2 instance on AWS

At this moment I have a sip trunk with 3CX server working, I need to make another one with the same one.

I have had an idea of add another NIC in the asterisk and add `externip` parameter in the sip.conf file to add anocher sip trunk and I did it. When I puted sip show peers in the asterisk console, it shows "Status OK (100 ms)" but in 3CX the traffic incoming was from the first trunk.

It's possible create this kind of sip trunk? or I need to launch another machine create a kind of bridge between my asterisk and 3CX?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Only way do that without starting second INSTANCE of asterisk is use chan_pjsip or combination of chan_pjsip+chan_sip.

For first variant you should do multiple endpoints entity. For second just put one channel on one ip, second on other ip.

You also can start more than one asterisk process on host by using

```
asterisk -C asterisk_config.conf
```